# How to keep a header when symmetrizing an adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I am using `symmetrize` function (**sna** package) to symmetrize an adjacency matrix that has row and column names. For example:
[sample matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4tWl.png)

I used the following command to import matrix in R:

```
y <- read.table("y.csv", header=T,row.names=1,na.strings="99", sep=",")
```

and then this command to symmetrize data:

```
y_s <-symmetrize(y,rule="strong", return.as.edgelist=FALSE)
```

After I run this command, the symmetrized matrix `y_s` no longer has row and column names. Is there any way I can modify this code so that row and column names are kept unchanged? Or, perhaps, there is a different way to symmetrize adjacency matrices? 
Thank you.

Comment: "After I run this code"? We do need this "this code" _and_ the code that makes all of the objects.

Comment: Please post the data not pictures of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the names disappear but you can reassign the names based on the original adjacency matrix.

```
rownames(x) <- rownames(y)
colnames(x) <- colnames(y)
```